# Automatically typeset math in section headings in bold-face

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sectioning, table-of-contents, bold

This question is motivated by a question asked me by a friend who is working on his thesis in mathematics. His section headings occasionally contain math, which:

- he would like to be in boldface to match the rest of the section title; but
- he would like to be medium-weight when it occurs in the table of contents, as with the rest of the section title.

He was using `\mathbf` to make the math boldface in his section headings; this of course also made them bold in the table of contents. I gave him a simple solution which inserted code at the beginning of the table of contents, which would make `\mathbf` pass its arguments unchanged. Of course, `\mathbf` also makes its arguments upright rather than math-italics, which I would also consider less than desirable; and it has no effect on *e.g.* greek characters, for which you would have to use something like the `\bm` command of `bm.sty` instead. (You could play the same trick with `\bm` as with `\mathbf` in the table of contents, but having to repeatedly use different math macros for all math in section headings to me seems inelegant.)

What would be the most elegant way to automatically render all math (including non-latin characters) in bold-face for section headings, but the normal medium-weight everywhere else (including the entries of the table of contents)?

Comment: Note that the weight of a character usually has mathematical meaning: `$a$` is not the same as `$\bm{a}$` (the package `bm` provides the command). If there are math formulas in titles, it would probably be best to avoid having them in boldface to begin with.

Comment: As people who frequently work with vectors, my friend and I are both quite familiar with notations which use boldface as a syntactic indicator. However, if working in a discipline where there is no particular use of boldface, the similarity of entities in the section heading to entities in the prose should be sufficient to suggest that the boldface does not serve to describe a different mathematical object, in which case uniformity of typesetting would be a greater desideratum than mitigating the (marginal) risk of confusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest thing is to patch `\@startsection` and `\@chapter` (assuming `book` or `report` class):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\@sect}{#8}{\boldmath #8}{}{}
\let\ori@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ori@chapter[\boldmath#1]{\boldmath#2}}
\makeatother
```

`#8` is the argument to `\@sect` that contains the title; but `\boldmath` will not leak to the table of contents nor to the headers (for headers it's sufficient to use `fancyhdr` and issue `\boldmath`, if bold headers are desired).

It doesn't work with `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, nor with `\chapter*`. It shouldn't be a problem to issue `\boldmath` in the argument of an occasional `\chapter*`.

Comment: Will this work if there is a mixture of maths and text? `\section{On euler's equation, $e^{i\pi}+1=0$}`

Comment: @Seamus Yes, of course. :) `\boldmath` is a declaration, not a command with arguments. When the section's title is typeset, it's in a group, so the declaration loses its effect afterwards.

Answer (score 74):

Here's a solution that I've found to work very well -- add the following to your document preamble

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```

(or just add the middle line to a .sty/.cls file, where the at-symbol escaping isn't needed.) This just modifies that `\bfseries` macro to include `\boldmath`. You also need to make sure that your font family contains bold math symbols, of course: not all do.

I'm not really sure why this isn't done by default... it seems an obviously desirable behaviour. Credit where it's due: I think this was supplied to me some years ago by Donald Arseneau on `comp.text.tex`.

(PS. Before finding out about this "trick" I wrote the hacky `maybemath` package, which is a far less elegant way to do this sort of thing but does also allow context-sensitive adaptation of math to sans-serif/roman fonts, and italic/upright styles. The latter may seem a bit strange given that math mode is already italicised by default, but is useful for when the math mode is only being used for access to sub/superscripting, in particular in the [hepparticles](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hepparticles/) package (see the `testhepparticles.pdf` example. A more elegant way to do this would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: Just as an addendum, I *really* like this answer. "it seems an obviously desirable behaviour"—I would wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: This has now become a permanent part of my standard preamble.

Comment: Such a simple solution....

Comment: Such an awesome solution. It works like a charm. Much thanks!

Comment: Wow, this works really amazing, it looks like this is exactly what was missing, thanks!!

Comment: When I use math symbols in the title of a theorem, for example \begin{theorem}[$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational] ... \end{theorem}, then this symbol also becomes bold, which should not be the case?

Comment: @SebastianBechtel This solution is for those who want math boldness to match that of the surrounding text, in whatever context. Personally I'd say if the theorem title is boldened, the math in it should be bold, too: it's just another sort of heading. This will lose some info if the boldness has semantic meaning, but that'll be clear in the body of the theorem. If essential, you could use \let to freeze the original \bfseries def and redefine the theorem environment to switch the math-unaware version back in... or redefine the theorem title to use a style other than bold.

Comment: @andybuckley Usually, the title is not bold, isn’t it? So in my case, I get “Theorem X (\sqrt{2} is irrational).”, where Theorem is in bold, everything in the parentheses except the math symbol is normal, and the math symbol is again bold.

Comment: @SebastianBechtel If I put \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} in my preamble (either before or after the \bfseries redefinition), and write
\begin{theorem}[Flibjibble's $x = \sqrt{2}$ theorem]
  A very important theorem on $x^2 = 2$\dots
\end{theorem}
then the whole of the square-bracketed theorem title appears bold in article class. Including the math, of course. All that's done is to include math in boldening context, so it shouldn't be possible to activate "by accident" when the surrounding context is not \bfseries or an explicit \boldmath

Comment: @andybuckley In the article class it works also fine for me, I use amsart.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it is possible to do this automatically, but here is a simpler "semi-automatic" solution.  Note that `\section` has two arguments:  the mandatory one sets section title, and the optional one (if present) sets the table of contents entry.  Here we use `\boldmath` in the mandatory argument, but not in the optional one.  Note also that bold math is not upright, as you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\section[First: $a=b$]{First: \boldmath{$a=b$}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, `\boldmath` does not look bad in TOC either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\section{First: \boldmath{$a=b$}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally like the second solution better: here math blends with the text both in the section title and TOC.

Comment: Good point about the section headings in the table of contents; but that will probably vary with different styles (_e.g._ in the case of my friend's thesis, apparently they aren't in boldface). For `article.cls`, the subsection headings in the table of contents aren't in boldface either. Having an automatic approach which is independent of documentclass and section-level would be more in the spirit of good LaTeX-artisanship.

Comment: This solution is problematic if you are using a style where the section headers show up at the topf pf the page, like for example ``book' ', because the secion headers will display math in biold and text in normal wight.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\boldmath} % documentclass: not memoir; works also with KOMA-script
\setsecheadstyle{\boldmath} % documentclass: memoir
```

But be aware about [@barbara-beeton's  comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108894/typesetting-formulas-in-section-titles-title-bold-toc-entry-isnt#comment238645_108894) at a similiar question:

> in some contexts it's not considered good practice to bold math just to follow the style of a title. if there's any chance that bold vs. non-bold has a distinct difference in meaning, introducing possible ambiguity isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

to expand on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124311/) answer by @andybuckley, the problem with `amsthm` discussed in the comments (I can't comment myself due to a lack of reputation) can be fixed by the following code:

```latex
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont\unboldmath(#3)}}}
\let\thmhead\thmhead@plain
\makeatother
```

The reason why the problem appears is that `amsthm` roughly does the following:

```latex
\begin{theorem}[extra note $a$]
is compiled to
{\bfseries Theorem 1 {\fontseries\mddefault\upshape extra note $a$}.}
```

This is why `extra note` appears normal while `$a$` appears in boldface if the fix is not applied.