# Typesetting formulas in section titles: Title bold, ToC entry isn't

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, memoir

I have a largeish document written with memoir, and I need mathematics formulas in section titles. The problem is that I can't get the formulas set in bold for the title, and non-bold for the table of contents. This MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\title{Minimal (Non) Working Example}
\author{The A. Uthor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Just some random title}

\section{The equation $a + \sqrt{x}$ looks ugly here\ldots}

  (Non-bold formula in bold title.)
  It looks fine in ToC.

\section{\protect\boldmath
           This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine
      \protect\unboldmath}

  It looks \emph{terrible} in ToC.

\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` (TeXlive 2013, Fedora 18) gives a ToC with the first equation OK, but a bad section title; while the second goes the other way around.

Comment: You can use the optional argument for the unbolded version: `\section[This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine]{\boldmath
           This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine
      \unboldmath}`

Comment: in some contexts it's not considered good practice to bold math just to follow the style of a title.  if there's any chance that bold vs. non-bold has a distinct difference in meaning, introducing possible ambiguity isn't a good idea.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right. But in my particular case that isn't a problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, boy do I feel stupid... I'd like to close this issue, could you please post that as an answer?

Comment: @vonbrand I have turned my comment into an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I quoted your comment in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266952/53982) at a similiar question in general. I hope it's ok.

Comment: @Dominik -- not a problem.  however, egreg had already made that point in his comment to the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for the unbolded version:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Just some random title}
\section[This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine]{\boldmath This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine \unboldmath}

\end{document}
```

If you are loading the `hyperref` package, you will also have to use `\texorpdfstring` to have a valid bookmark:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Just some random title}
\section[\texorpdfstring{This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine}{Some variant with no TeX}]{\boldmath This $a^2 + b^3$ equation looks fine \unboldmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `hyperref` package should have been my next question, true. But that one I've alreday tamed.

Answer (score 2):

In connection to Barbaras comment, and there is no distinction in the document between bold and un bold formula, the easiest to do is simply to add `\boldmath` to the section font setting (via `\setsecheadstyle`)