# Complex math expressions inside titles of sections produce the error TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: math-mode, section-titles

I get the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]` for the line 47 of the following .tex file.

I get such an error whenever there is a complicated math expression inside the title of a section. Such expressions compile successfully when in the body, but fail to compile when in the title. How to fix this?

Here is my .tex file.

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix,twocolumn,amsmath,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,nofootinbib,tighten]{revtex4}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\pg}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{amssymb}   % for math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\ensuremath\boldsymbol{#1}} % bold font for vectors

\usepackage{amsfonts, relsize, color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcommand{\expect}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Some math expressions like this works $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ when inside titles of the sections.

But complicated expressions containing $\bra{}$, $\ket{}$, or $\langle$ or $\rangle$ inside section or subsection does not work.

\onecolumngrid
\appendix

\section{Some math expressions like this works $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ when inside title}

Here it works $\bra{\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{k}} u_{\vec{k}}} \tilde{\vec{P}}(\vec{k}) \ket{u_{\vec{k}}}$, but this does not work when inside section's title.

%The following fails to compile

\section{Calculation of $\bra{\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{k}} u_{\vec{k}}} \tilde{\vec{P}}(\vec{k}) \ket{u_{\vec{k}}}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try  to suppress it from the bookmarks with `\texorpdfstring{math}{something for bookmarks}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When I use `\texorpdfstring{math}{something for bookmarks}`, it does not look like a title of a section. The `math` goes to the body. And also, I don't need bookmarks because I intend to write a paper without any content page.

Comment: `\ensuremath` takes an argument so `\ensuremath\boldsymbol{#1}`is `\ensuremath{\boldsymbol}{#1}` so will do entirely the wrong thing if not used in math mode. delete the `\ensuremath`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did you mean `\section{\texorpdfstring{math}{something for bookmarks}}` ?

Comment: Off-topic: the `subfigure` package is badly deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use the `subfig` package if the document employs one of the `revtex` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For section titles it must be used `\texorpdfstring` (provided by `hyperref`) for the bookmarks (no math symbols) and the TOC.

(If bookmarks are not needed see the end of this answer.)

`\texorpdfstring` has two arguments: the first is the normal TeX code (used in the title and the TOC), the second is a string, which can be used as replacement for the TeX code in the bookmarks.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180269/161015 for a more complete explanation.

[image: c]

(Use `revtex4-2` and simplify your preamble  of repeated packages.)

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,floatfix,twocolumn,amsmath,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,nofootinbib,tighten]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
\usepackage{bm} % bold math font
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{comment} % 
\usepackage{textcomp} % 

\usepackage{xcolor} % 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\expect}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}

\newcommand\vecx[1]{%
\texorpdfstring{\bm{\vec{#1}}}{}} % bold font for vectors  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

Some math expressions like this works $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ when inside titles of the sections.

But complicated expressions containing $\bra{}$, $\ket{}$, or $\langle$ or $\rangle$ inside section or subsection does not work.

\onecolumngrid
\appendix

\section{Some math expressions like this works $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ when inside title}

Here it works $\bra{\frac{\partial}{\partial \vecx{k}} u_{\vecx{k}}} \tilde{\vecx{P}}(\vecx{k}) \ket{u_{\vecx{k}}}$, but this does not work when inside section's title.

%The following fails to compile

\section{Calculation of 
    $\bra{\frac{\partial}{\partial \vecx{k}} u_{\vecx{k}}} \tilde{\vecx{P}}(\vecx{k}) \ket{u_{\vecx{k}}}$
}

 \end{document}
```

If you do not need bookmarks use:

```
\newcommand\vecx[1]{%
\bm{\vec{#1}}} % bold font for vectors  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref} % supress bookmarks <<<<<<<<<<<
```