# acronyms in math mode

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, bold

I write my thesis and I need a little help. I don't write a thesis in English. I'm using acronyms via glossary package as a template requires.

`\newacronym{EM}{EM}{Electromagnetic}` work perfectly, but `\newacronym{Q}{$Q$}{Electric charge}` don't work as I want to. At the end of the thesis is situated a list of acronyms. This list is like bold EM and explanantion. However, in the next line Q is in math mode as I need but it's not bold. Later, I'll use a greek symbols as well so I need to know how to add them as acronyms to the list and be a bold in the list and thin in normal text.

Thanks for help.

P.S. Sorry for bad English It's not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, I found a solution by andybuckley [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124311/173645), please have a look at it.

The concept is to add `\boldmath` to `\bfseries` macro.
You can do it just adding the following code in the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```